# 502 Bad Gateway Error from RStudio Cloud running on AWS EC2

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rstudio-server

I had an EC2 instance running RStudio Cloud. Somewhere in the midst of heavy-duty computing, the instance became unresponsive and I had  to restart it. After the restart, the RStudio Cloud launch page throws me an 502 Bad Gateway Error.

Would appreciate if anyone could help troubleshooting it.

Latest system log is pasted below:

```
[    8.403877] cloud-init[624]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[    8.409586] cloud-init[624]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[    8.413668] cloud-init[624]:   File "/usr/bin/cloud-init", line 11, in <module>
[    8.418772] cloud-init[624]:     load_entry_point('cloud-init==18.5', 'console_scripts', 'cloud-init')()
[    8.424939] cloud-init[624]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 892, in main
[    8.431151] cloud-init[624]:     get_uptime=True, func=functor, args=(name, args))
[    8.436229] cloud-init[624]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 2517, in log_time
[    8.442520] cloud-init[624]:     ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
[    8.447102] cloud-init[624]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 670, in status_wrapper
[    8.454012] cloud-init[624]:     atomic_helper.write_json(status_path, status)
[    8.458733] cloud-init[[624]: [0;32m  OK  [0m]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/atomic_helper.py", line 40, in write_json
Started Network Service.
[    8.464400] cloud-init         [624]: Starting Wait for Network to be Configured...    omode="w", mode=mode)

[[    8.475262] [0;1;31mFAILED[0mcloud-init] [624]: Failed to start Network Name Resolution.  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/atomic_helper.py", line 33, in write_file

See 'systemctl status systemd-resolved.service' for details.
[    8.485895] cloud-init[624]:     raise e
[[    8.490733] [0;32m  OK  [0mcloud-init] [624]: Reached target Network.  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/atomic_helper.py", line 27, in write_file

[[    8.500524] [0;32m  OK  [0mcloud-init] [624]: Reached target Host and Network Name Lookups.    tf.close()

[[    8.507179] [0;32m  OK  [0mcloud-init] [624]: Started Wait for Network to be Configured.
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 650, in close
[[    8.516216] [0;32m  OK  [0mcloud-init] [624]: Stopped Network Name Resolution.    self._closer.close()

[    8.524024] [cloud-init[0;1;31mFAILED[0m[624]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 584, in close] 
Failed to start Network Name Resolution.
See 'systemctl status systemd-resolved.service' for details.
[    8.532734] cloud-init[624]:     self.file.close()
         [    8.538251] Starting Initial cloud-init job (metadata service crawler)...
cloud-init[624]: OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
[[0;32m  OK  [0m[    8.545899] ] cloud-initStopped Network Name Resolution.[624]: Error in sys.excepthook:

[    8.553074] cloud-init[[624]: [0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Traceback (most recent call last):Failed to start Network Name Resolution.

See 'systemctl status systemd-resolved.service' for details.[    8.558939] 
cloud-init[624]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 155, in apport_excepthook
[[0;32m  OK  [0m[    8.570083] ] Stopped Network Name Resolution.cloud-init[624]: 
    pr.write(f)
[[    8.577451] [0;1;31mFAILED[0mcloud-init] [624]: Failed to start Network Name Resolution.
  File "/usr/lib/python3
```